# kotlin.Any not found when enabling Proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson, proguard

Am seeing a crash at runtime when Proguard is enabled. I've basically kept everything in Proguard rules.

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-addconfigurationdebugging
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn ***

-keep class *** { *** *; <methods>; <init>(...);}
-keep interface *** { *** *; }
-keep @interface *** { *** *; }
-keep enum *** { *** *; }
-keepattributes ***
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!code/allocation/variable,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!method/removal/*,!class/unboxing/enum
```

Yes this is probably not the best use of Proguard, but even this results in the following crash

```
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.AssertionError: Built-in class kotlin.Any is not found
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns$3.invoke(KotlinBuiltIns.java:113)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns$3.invoke(KotlinBuiltIns.java:108)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getBuiltInClassByName(KotlinBuiltIns.java:362)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getAny(KotlinBuiltIns.java:367)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getAnyType(KotlinBuiltIns.java:642)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getNullableAnyType(KotlinBuiltIns.java:647)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getDefaultBound(KotlinBuiltIns.java:652)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.TypeParameterDescriptorImpl.createWithDefaultBound(TypeParameterDescriptorImpl.java:56)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$MockClassDescriptor.<init>(NotFoundClasses.kt:55)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:44)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:22)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses.getClass(NotFoundClasses.kt:92)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer$typeConstructor$1.invoke(TypeDeserializer.kt:109)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.typeConstructor(TypeDeserializer.kt:113)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.simpleType(TypeDeserializer.kt:75)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.type(TypeDeserializer.kt:63)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer.valueParameters(MemberDeserializer.kt:417)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer.loadConstructor(MemberDeserializer.kt:342)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.computePrimaryConstructor(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:122)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.access$computePrimaryConstructor(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$primaryConstructor$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:65)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$primaryConstructor$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.getUnsubstitutedPrimaryConstructor(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:126)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.computeConstructors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:129)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.access$computeConstructors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$constructors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:66)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$constructors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.getConstructors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:137)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructorDescriptors(KClassImpl.kt:200)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:91)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:44)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:92)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getConstructors(Unknown Source:7)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructors(KClassImpl.kt:235)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:144)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.findKotlinParameterName(KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.kt:115)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.findImplicitPropertyName(KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.kt:31)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:490)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreatorParam(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:485)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreators(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:465)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:313)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:292)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:276)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:224)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:220)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4405)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4214)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3182)
11-17 20:23:17.172 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at 
...
```

No Kotlin related files were excluded in build.gradle. the std lib is included, as there's no problem when Proguard is disabled

Currently using Proguard 7.1.1, same problem with 6.0.3. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is not best solution but you can test below code for yourself with investigating step by step

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
    -dontshrink
    -dontoptimize
    -printmapping build/libs/output/obfuscation.map
    -keepattributes
    -adaptclassstrings
    -dontnote
    -dontwarn

# Keep Android classes
-keep class ** extends android.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Keep serializable classes & fields
-keep class ** extends java.io.Serializable {
    <fields>;
}

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}
```

Comment: this is more restrictive than the one I posted right?

Comment: You know every primitive types extends class Any , so your problem was with obfuscating this classes , below code have to avoid obfuscating kotlin classes

-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

Comment: Mark as ANSWER if my answer is correct please

Comment: added those rules, still same problem

Comment: Looks like the entire kotlin folder in the root of the APK is removed. Does anyone know why that's the case? I posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207298/proguard-removing-kotlin-directory-in-apk